# Make a priority queue limit its memory in C++

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, stdvector

I am using a `priority_queue<unsigned long,vector<unsigned long>,greater<unsigned long> >` in C++ and I have a memory limit of 16MB. My program only needs 10MB, but as soon as it gets to 8653464 Bytes it tries to double its capacity and throws a `bad_alloc`.

Is there a way to stop this using my current implementation? Can a `priority_queue` have log(n) time still if I switch to a `deque` [from a `vector`]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switching to `deque` is very sensible approach. It grow by fixed number, not by x2 as `vector`.  And complexity should stay `O(log N)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  `priority_queue` is a container adaptor, and by default it is based on `vector`.  I think the easiest way to solve your problem would be to make a subclass of vector which refuses to grow too large and doesn't double when it gets close to the limit, but rather just goes to the limit.  You could also use the regular vector class but with a custom allocator instead, but that's probably more work.

Answer (score 1):

`vector` offers worse complexities than `deque`, and `deque`'s growth is much more predictable and controllable. If you don't need the absolutely fastest iteration on God's green earth and a couple of blue Earths too (or compatibility for a C array), then `deque` is the superior container for all uses.